# Use axios with all and spread function to renew and attach JWT

Tags: javascript, axios

We have a vue.js app with various components that make network calls via a global Axios instance. Each network call needs an Authorization: Bearer header with a JWT.

We also make use of the Axios All/Spread functions to concurrently fetch multiple resources from our API. Here is an example of the spread function:

```
axios.all([getUserAccount(), getUserPermissions()])
  .then(axios.spread(function (acct, perms) {
    // Both requests are now complete
  }));
```

I have added an Axios Request Interceptor to my global axios instance to fetch a new JWT in the event that the current JWT is about to expire OR if fully expired, present a login popup to the user to re-authenticate.

It looks like this:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  if (jwtNearlyExpired(token)) {
    return fetchRenewedToken().then((response) => {
      config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + response.data.token
      return config
    })
  } else if (jwtIsExpired(token)) {
    return triggerLoginPopup().then((response) => {
      config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + response.data.token
      return config
    })
  } else {
    config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token
    return config
  }
}, (error) => {
  return Promise.reject(error)
})
```

The problem I'm having is that the spread function triggers multiple async calls at the same time, so I can, for example, have cases where I trigger 3 login popups at the same time via the interceptor.

Is there a better way for renewing/managing JWTs and login flows via Axios prior to making Axios calls?

Comment: What is "spread function"?

Comment: Axios Spread example added above

Comment: Have not tried axios. Does `axios.spread()` return a function? What is the expected result?

Comment: Axios.all() and spread will resolve when all promises are finished. So its used to concurrently make async calls then resolve when all are finished. So in my case, say I'm making 3 concurrent calls, it will hit my interceptor three times immediately.

Comment: Not an expert with this method of authentication, but maybe it's possible somehow to cancel subsequent requests in case of an error? https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation

Comment: Are you sure that `axios.spread()` is not called immediately? And if it is, does `axios.spread()` return a function reference to be called when the `Promise` fulfills? `.then()` expects a function reference or an anonymous function, not a function that is called immediately, though if a function is called within `.then()` the function will not await the `Promise` object that `.then()` is chained to.

Comment: Axios.spread takes a callback for when all the promises in Axios.all are resolved. There's some documentation about it on the repo main readme https://github.com/axios/axios.